# Different permission for different user on Excel Online

Tags: permissions, excel-online

I need to create Excel on-line workbook with different permissions sheets. more like some users can see some sheets while other can't edit, etc.
can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can allow certain users to edit certain areas of the sheet by using "Allow Users to Edit Ranges"

https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-bdb8252f-d605-45cb-9712-137925867ad4

You can setup a way to hide certain sheets with a login via macros but it need some coding that is beyond my scope currently